# Can I delete current file opened with nano?

Tags: nano

Can I delete current file opened with nano?
That means after I opened file with `nano <file>`, press a shortcut key for delete `<file>`.

Comment: This question would be better received on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @JonnyHenly What's difference?

Comment: From what I've seen, *usually* the users on SO give better answers to questions pertaining to programming, whereas the users on SU give better answers to questions pertaining to software.

Answer (score 2):

**No, you cannot.** Actually I haven't seen any TextEditor that allows you to Delete the file. You can simply use:

```
rm -rf <file>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Please remove `-rf` from the command ("too many pending edits" on SO)!